# Animated gif creating on iPhone (some C library)?

Tags: iphone, export, save, animated-gif

Any reliable third party library?

I've found [Jitsik's Giraffe](http://jitsik.com/wordpress/?p=208) so far, but he said that it has poor palette handling.

Any other solution (some C library maybe)?

Answer (score 0):

With ImageMagick.
[3fr.ms](http://3fr.ms/) implementation: [Using ImageMagick to create animated GIFs on the iPhone](http://brainbowapps.com/articles/2010/using-imagemagick-to-create-animated-gifs-on-the-iphone.html)